# Новая версия - новое шифрование!

Tags: c#, google-chrome, шифрование

Проблема: обновил хром, хочу программным способом получить все логины/пароли.

Версия хрома:    **Версия 64.0.3282.140 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)**

В новой версии пароли для определенного пользователя, хранятся в определенной папке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле Login Data (формат SqlLite)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С оперы расшифровывать получается, но с Хрома не выходит.

Для примера взял 3 браузера, везде зашифровано "admin", это массивы байтов в ANSI кодировке.

Опера

```
1,0,0,0,208,140,157,223,1,21,209,17,140,122,0,192,79,194,151,235,1,0,0,0,52,151,96,161,235,229,60,72,184,157,92,157,157,74,73,192,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,16,102,0,0,0,1,0,0,32,0,0,0,251,139,217,18,210,62,209,4,7,96,14,64,54,189,139,102,8,159,244,48,192,66,13,249,194,126,157,195,158,224,181,124,0,0,0,0,14,128,0,0,0,2,0,0,32,0,0,0,77,172,93,225,85,238,237,104,233,121,142,30,1,134,139,227,8,15,73,9,77,20,246,65,136,102,28,192,169,249,46,199,16,0,0,0,113,58,177,198,186,184,47,203,157,188,202,145,176,149,215,244,64,0,0,0,133,88,174,73,87,192,4,39,76,199,100,182,30,228,31,221,238,254,239,143,128,42,29,127,151,88,78,78,102,174,16,143,34,118,120,88,48,232,45,128,120,125,33,88,119,214,188,221,122,15,36,75,113,242,68,157,17,209,143,145,20,220,207,71
```

Амиго

```
1,0,0,0,208,140,157,223,1,21,209,17,140,122,0,192,79,194,151,235,1,0,0,0,52,151,96,161,235,229,60,72,184,157,92,157,157,74,73,192,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,16,102,0,0,0,1,0,0,32,0,0,0,251,139,217,18,210,62,209,4,7,96,14,64,54,189,139,102,8,159,244,48,192,66,13,249,194,126,157,195,158,224,181,124,0,0,0,0,14,128,0,0,0,2,0,0,32,0,0,0,77,172,93,225,85,238,237,104,233,121,142,30,1,134,139,227,8,15,73,9,77,20,246,65,136,102,28,192,169,249,46,199,16,0,0,0,113,58,177,198,186,184,47,203,157,188,202,145,176,149,215,244,64,0,0,0,133,88,174,73,87,192,4,39,76,199,100,182,30,228,31,221,238,254,239,143,128,42,29,127,151,88,78,78,102,174,16,143,34,118,120,88,48,232,45,128,120,125,33,88,119,214,188,221,122,15,36,75,113,242,68,157,17,209,143,145,20,220,207,71
```

Хром

```
1,0,0,0,208,140,157,223,1,21,209,17,140,122,0,192,79,194,151,235,1,0,0,0,52,151,96,161,235,229,60,72,184,157,92,157,157,74,73,192,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,16,102,0,0,0,1,0,0,32,0,0,0,72,20,70,217,15,123,38,190,137,58,239,198,214,149,255,220,140,203,12,123,183,105,65,16,219,228,208,93,28,9,160,75,0,0,0,0,14,128,0,0,0,2,0,0,32,0,0,0,181,156,73,9,37,11,90,122,0,16,81,132,76,50,146,65,11,1,42,220,38,138,99,128,131,114,255,127,210,239,239,172,16,0,0,0,48,67,77,214,135,120,209,220,26,109,6,186,3,133,67,9,64,0,0,0,35,215,200,200,26,204,200,57,209,51,165,130,181,210,82,206,250,165,223,219,22,156,25,199,167,167,202,38,148,5,181,45,184,239,75,61,155,94,199,6,66,131,180,189,134,202,87,72,170,84,180,120,20,232,89,248,204,215,182,154,203,92,73,129
```

---

---

---

Вот различия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Амиго и Опера одинаковы.

Расшифровывал Амигу и Оперу по этой статье:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/134982/

( библиотека из статьи https://github.com/ashumkin/Chrome-passwords/blob/master/DPAPI/Program.cs )

Помогите расшифровать, на языке C#